# Killing a node.js server

Tags: node.js, process

I'm have a monitor that auto-daemonizes processes and manages them.

So I have this node.js program that somehow spawns another process. My code uses no forking or anything like that, it just has an infinite loop using setInterval that does some db work.

This is how it's run:

```
node /path/to/program.js >> program.log 2>&1
```

After this, `top -bcn1|grep program.js` shows:

```
24763 ubuntu    20   0  695m  21m 5464 S    0  0.3   0:00.39 node /path/to/program.js                                                                                                   
25053 ubuntu    20   0  4264  580  484 S    0  0.0   0:00.01 sh -c node /path/to/program.js >> program.log 2>&1
```

My process monitor then sets a pid file with 25053, so when I tell it to restart the program it kills 25053, starts the program again, and now the output of the previous command is:

```
24763 ubuntu    20   0  695m  21m 5464 S    0  0.3   0:00.39 node /path/to/program.js                                                                                                   
23520 ubuntu    20   0  630m  21m 5464 S    0  0.3   0:00.39 node /path/to/program.js                                                                                                   
23012 ubuntu    20   0  4264  580  484 S    0  0.0   0:00.01 sh -c node /path/to/program.js >> program.log 2>&1
```

So how do I make it so the "child" process or whatever it is is also killed?

I have a feeling this is something basic in node but I haven't found an answer yet.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible yet. See [this pull request](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/2832).

Comment: Does that apply even if I'm not spawning nor forking anything?

Comment: Misunderstood the question. I don't believe it does apply. Sorry.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but isn't the "other" process just the shell showing the output from your main node script, waiting for it to finish?

Answer (score 0):

you need to listen for the exit event off of process...

try:

```
var children = [];
//keep track of the child processes...
process.on('exit',function(){
    children.forEach(function(child){
        child.kill('SIGINT');
    });
});
```

NOTE: in the children, you'll want to listen for 'SIGINT' etc.

see: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: note... you may need to do a pskill etc, keeping a list of process id's to kill.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but again, I'm not spawning any child processes :)